# Counting Heronian triangles based on area to perimeter ratios

Tags: triangles

For Heronian triangles t with the perimeter p and area a,
there are five distinct triangles with the area equal to the perimeter:

If a=p, count(t) = 5, if a=2p, count(t)=18.

For the area being an integer multiple of the perimeter, what
is the sequence given by count(t), ie starting 5,18,...

source: Numberphile video 12min 43sec

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIjeCKPHbso

Comment: The sequence is this: [OEIS A007237](http://oeis.org/A007237)

Comment: It might or might not be relevant, but, with the semiperimeter being $s=p/2$, the triangle's inradius is $r=a/s$; that is, the set of all such triangles with a specified area to perimeter ratio is the set of all such triangles with a specified inradius. Which might not necessarily be an integer.